# Two processes handling their own lines of code in one main function (c++)

Tags: c++, createprocess, createfile

So my task goes like this:

The program needs 2 processes **in one main function**

- First process creates or opens a file "log.txt" which is in the same directory where the program is located. Then it adds user input to this file.
- Second process is a "monitor" of this file. It checks if the file exists, shows its size and shows how many characters were entered since the second process started.

**Note** that I am aware that the program itself is a process, but it needs to be done like that. There are some "tips" to use a file as mutex (CreateFile parameters) that would be the dsShareMode with FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE parameter.

Now my question is: how do you create 2 processes to handle its own line of code? I've seen many examples of `CreateProcess` function but I don't really understand the first two parameters of this function

- lpApplicationName
  and
- lpCommandLine

What am I supposed to pass to it in order to run 2 processes, one to handle the user input and the other to be the "monitor"?

The first process is meant to handle those lines of code:

```
        std::string buffer;
        std::cout << "Enter your text:" << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, buffer);
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("log.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        DWORD written = 0;
        WriteFile(hFile, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size(), &written, NULL);
```

While the second process should only care about this:

```
hFile = CreateFile("log.txt", FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            std::cout << "CreateFile error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD size = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
            std::cout << "\nCurrent file size: " << size << std::endl;
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }

        int stringLength = 0;
        for(int i=0; buffer[i]; i++)
            stringLength++;

            std::cout << "\nCharacters given since last startup: " << stringLength << std::endl;
```

Comment: Does it have to be two processes? Using two threads seems more natural given the problem described.

Comment: Yes, the task has to use 2 processes. But as I pointed out, the first two parameters of the CreateProcess functions are the thing I don't really understand.

Comment: Option the first: have two separate executables. Option the second: have one executable but pass commandline option to specify which mode it should run as. Note that this solution is very unidiomatic; normally one would use threads as @john said.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) and the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes) it links to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a separate `helper.exe`, you can do:

```
CreateProcess(nullptr, "helper logger-mode", ...)
```

and

```
CreateProcess(nullptr, "helper monitor-mode", ...)
```

This will create two processes that see either `logger-mode` or `monitor-mode` in their second argument (`argv[1]`).

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. I don't have a separate helper.exe, however I've seen similar solution before. I could pass argv[0] as lpApplicationName and I the could pass the parameters in lpCommandLine but I don't really know how to pass them. Could you show me an example on how to pass argument via CreateProcess function?

Comment: That is what my answer already does..? Just replace the first argument with `argv[0]`

Comment: The command line parameter should just be a string that follows the windows quoting conventions. This string is split into tokens and each token ends up in the `argv` of the newly spawned process. In my example the mode will be in `argv[1], as I said. If you're still confused, think about it as typing that string into a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to demand having the same program being run as two separate processes.  If that is the case, the program will need to handle command line arguments and tailor its functionality accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

@Botje I've managed to do something like that. Could you take a look at tell me if such solution is acceptable?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
std::string cmdline1 = "main Proc1";
std::string cmdline2 = "main Proc2";
std::string buffer;
HANDLE hFile;

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    CreateProcess(argv[0], const_cast<char *>(cmdline1.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
    CreateProcess(argv[0], const_cast<char *>(cmdline2.c_str()), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

if(strcmp(argv[1], "Proc1"))
{
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your text:" << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, buffer);
        hFile = CreateFile("log.txt", FILE_APPEND_DATA, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
        DWORD written = 0;
        WriteFile(hFile, buffer.c_str(), buffer.size(), &written, NULL);
    }
}

if(strcmp(argv[1], "Proc2"))
{
    DWORD charactersGiven = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        hFile = CreateFile("log.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
            if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                std::cout << "CreateFile error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                DWORD size = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
                std::cout << "\nCurrent file size: " << size << std::endl;
                if(charactersGiven == 0)
                charactersGiven = size;

                std::cout << "Characters given since last startup: " << size - charactersGiven << std::endl;
            }
            Sleep(4000);
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: strcmp() compares two strings character by character; while you're comparing argv[1] to  "Proc1" and "Proc2", you have passed command line params as "main Proc1" and "main Proc2". So it may fail.

Comment: @Zoomln I have to disagree with you. I am passing the cmdline1 and cmdline2 as lpCommandLine and it says 'The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the lpCommandLine string' so because there is a white space, everything that comes after it is taken as parameter. I've tested it and it appears to work as it should, I just wonder if anything could be done better.

Comment: And you only want to spawn new processes if therr is no argument (check `argc`) . Otherwise you have a fork bomb that will keep spawning processes forever. Also, strcmp returns 0 if strings are equal. I would just convert `argv[1]` into a std::string ASAP, much easier to work with.